# How to use variables in PostgreSQL transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

How in Postgresql inside a transaction to get values ​​into a variable, and if SELECT did not return anything, throw an error, and if SELECT returned data, then use them in the transaction?

Like this:

```
BEGIN;

@activeRounds = SELECT * FROM "rounds" WHERE status = 'active';

if(!@activeRounds) {
  RAISE ERROR "Has no Active rounds"
};

INSERT INTO "bet"
  (user_id, round_id)
VALUES
  (100, @activeRound[0].id)


COMMIT;
```

how to do something similar in one request within a transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt following code to your table structure:

```
begin;
do
$$
declare
 v int;
begin
 select c1 into v from t1 where  k1=1;
 if not found 
 then
  raise exception 'no row found';
 else
  insert into t2(c2) values(v);
 end if;
end;
$$;
commit;
```

Note the difference bewteen `begin;` to start a transaction and `begin` to start a pl/pgSQL block.

Answer (score 0):

Write a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement in [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html).

Like every SQL statement, `DO` runs in a single transaction. PL/pgSQL is a procedural language that has variables and conditional processing.

Comment: Are you sure that all code inside DO block runs inside a transaction, if so can I have reference please?

Comment: Yes,, I am sure. Unless you add a `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` to the code, it will run in a single transaction. No reference; you'll have to try it out.