# PgAdmin: syntax to set a variable for use in a postgresql transaction

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am working with scripts that have the following syntax (example only):

```sql
BEGIN;
@set some_var = 'some value'

insert into foo (setting, name) values (:some_var, 'blahblah');

COMMIT;
```

...the script runs in dbeaver against postgres but fails in pgAdmin against the same postgres db. I was informed that this syntax is specific to dbeaver. If so, what is the equivalent that would work in pgAdmin (i.e. setting a variable for the duration of a script and being able to reference it inside sql statements like the above)?

Answer (score 1):

in function use special keyword

```
DECLARE
    Val1 text;
    Val2 text;
    Val3 integer;
begin

insert into foo (setting, name) values (Val1 , Val2 );
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html

this code you can use in transactions. inside begin;/commit; statements

```
begin;
do
$$
declare
    Val1 text;
    Val2 text;
begin
    Val1='asdasd';
    Val2='ssssss';
    insert into foo (setting, name) values (Val1 , Val2 );
end;
$$;
commit;
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not writing a function, it's just a database seed script to insert lots of data :)

Comment: use example code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568057/how-to-use-variables-in-postgresql-transaction